Session storage gets cleared when navigating to another URL on the same tab
I'm encountering an issue with session storage in my web application When I navigate to another URL within the same tab, the session storage seems to get cleared.
Here's the scenario:

I set some data in session storage using  session storage.set('key', 'value').

Then, I navigate to another URL within the same tab using window.location.href ='url'.

Reaching the new URL, I try to retrieve the data using sessionStorage.get('key'), but it return null.


This behaviour is unexpected to me because I expect session storage to persist within the same tab until the tab is closed or session ends.
function in my web app:

sessionStorageSyncReducer
return localStorageSync({})
clearState(reducer)

I've checked for any accidental clearing of session storage in my code but I couldn't find anything. Are there any specific reason why session storage might be getting cleared? is there an way to ensure that session storage persists even when navigating to another URL within the same tab?

Could you show us the code you have so far ?

It is supposed to be this : sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
also sessionStorage is domain specific. have you checked these two things

@TusharShahi Thank you for your response. Yes, I am using sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value') correctly in my code. Additionally, I am aware that session storage is domain-specific. Here’s a bit more detail on my issue:
The initial URL where I set the session storage is within the same domain as the URL I navigate to.
For example, I set the item on https://example.com/update/page1 and then navigate to https://example.com/change/page2.
Despite this, the session storage seems to be cleared or inaccessible when I try to retrieve it on page2.

To change URL without clearing your session storage, you need to use the HTML History API. You can read the History Api Docs. In the web apps I have worked on, they always use the history api to change tabs.
Usually the code to change url in the same page looks like this:
history.push('/your-url-route')
Where /your-url-route can be something like /login.
